# java.lang.IllegalStateException: CookieSyncManager::createInstance() needs to be called before CookieSyncManager::getInstance()

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview, webviewclient

I am trying to get cookies in webview on shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method and i got this error. Please have a look at my code below,

```
WebViewClient loginClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            final String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);

            //Some Code after this
        }
 }
```

And i m getting this error,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CookieSyncManager::createInstance() needs to be called before CookieSyncManager::getInstance()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);` in your Activity's `onCreate()` Method. The error clearly says `createInstance()` need to be called before calling `getInstance()`.

Comment: I am also seeing the same error. I am calling CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this) in the onCreate method and CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync() in onResume and CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync() in onPause. Still I see the same error sometimes